# iOS MDM with automatic updates of Enterprise Apps

Tags: ios, mdm, osx-server

We are a small IT team that needs to purchase between 20-100 iOS devices (iPhones) to hand out to external partners. These devices will be setup once, and then leave the premises to pretty much never ever come back physically.

The devices needs to be fully locked to our application. We won't allow surfing, emailing, phonecalls, text messages etc.

I need to set this up as easy as possible. Then I need to install our application (developed in-house) and once I create an update for this app **all** devices needs to be updated OTA. Updates to the iOS firmware should only be available if I say so. I don't want the user to be prompted to update iOS in case our application is not compatible yet.

From my understanding, I know I need some kind of MDM solution (Preferably Apple Configurator or the MDM server built into OS X Server in Yosemite) as well as an Apple Enterprise Developer account.

I'm looking for step by step instructions on how to set this up to be failproof. If any certificate is messed up, or expired at a later stage and the devices would end up "useless" it is nearly **impossible** for me to get to the devices physically.

Thank you for any responses, I'm in charge of quite a important part of the business, and I have no previous experience of this (I don't want to f' up)

Comment: Per my enterprise Apple rep: They can work with the business team at the retail stores.  While each store doesn't have a singularly dedicated SE, they all have access to one.  There was also the online business store route, but they've all merged now that <redacted> is on board.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very large, so I'm going to only address a few specific points that should get you going in the right direction.

If the devices are bought by a company or institution, you should look into supervising the device (a process which asserts that this device is owned by a company or institution and so certain restrictions normally unavailable to BYOD are available on this device for MDM).  Ideally, you'll purchase your devices straight from Apple in the US and then enroll them in the Device Enrollment Program (https://www.apple.com/education/it/dep/).  This will allow you to configure the devices so that every time they are erased, they will become supervised again and re-enrolled with your chosen MDM server and configuration (and also give you the option to lock MDM so that it is unremovable).

Configurator is not your friend if you're not going to have physical access to the device.  You'll want to use a MDM server and should look at a third-party vendor for the best experience (see AirWatch and MobileIron to start with).  An MDM server will be able to push install and update profiles and apps on the devices and so you should look heavily into this.

If the devices will be locked into a single application, look at Single App Mode.  By pushing down a profile by MDM, you can lock the device into a single app, but only on SUPERVISED devices.  You'll also want to look at the restrictions available for disabling things like Safari and such.  The Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference and the Configuration Profile Reference are both your friends here.

You will NOT be able to prevent devices from updating iOS itself.  This is a purposeful design choice from Apple and so you need to be testing your software against the developer betas to ensure it works before release or else you're out of luck.

Go check out the Apple Enterprise page (https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/).  Some good videos are the WWDC 2014 "Managing Apple Devices" and "Building Apps for Business and Education".